# When downloading a file, why are modern browsers "unfair" when compared to wget?

Tags: wget, https

> Why do modern web-browsers behave unfair compared to a regular download using “wget”?

I'm aware the question is fairly vague (I took it from a recent exam in my networking course), and I could not answer it. Does anyone have an idea what is meant by "fair"? The only thing I could think of is that browsers have a cache and don't have to download the whole website each time it is visited, but that doesn't really make them "behave unfair". Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: wget is a file downloader and doesn't have anything to do with a browser or the content of that file. Not quite sure why an instructor tries to compare apples with bananas

Answer (score 1):

I have a few theories:

- [Caching](http://shoulderiblamecaching.com/)
- Automatic showing (while with wget you need to find the file, then display it with a **browser**)
- You might need to download js scripts as well.
- [Cookies](https://www.theraleighregister.com/cookies19.html)